# Cause: failed to find target with hash string 'android-N'

Tags: android, android-studio

Today, I'm newbie in android studio.

I have updated the latest version of andriod studio

When I have opened an old projekct and started compiling the project I retrieve a 
error message that is "Cause: failed to find target with hash string 'android-N'"

```
What should I do in order to use this old project in the updated android studio?
```

Thank you!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Sourcecode from the file build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

android N is not installed in your sdk
Just click on the link written in the error:

Open Android SDK Manager
and it will show you the dialogs that will help you to install the required sdk for your project.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I can't find a android N in the sdk manager. What part am I missing?

Comment: android 7.0 Nougat is android N  if you still have the problem try install the 7.1.1

Comment: hey try to change this in your build.gradle  if its `compileSdkVersion 'android-N'`  make it `compileSdkVersion  24`  and change targetSdkVersion to 24

Comment: I can't find the text compileSdkVersion in gradle. What file in Gradle Script can I find it?
I hav now uploaded a new picture. Same problem occur when I have updated the android sdk. Thank you!

Comment: copy and past your build.gradle  here's how to find it [image] (http://www.android-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/build-gradle.png)

Comment: not that one this is the top-level build  you need  the build.gradle (module:app)

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no build.gradle (module: app) in the old project.

Comment: you need to find a way how to add one its important for the app to work properly . and now paste your manifest.xml file

Comment: Today, I'm using material about how to use android by reading a book. This author has provided some material that you can use as tutorial's coding material.

Comment: One of the project do not work that is why I have uploaded my question that is stackoverflow.

Comment: It is one of the project from the material that is defect and the remaining project works well.

Comment: Recently, I tried new and existing project that use and old api version. Before and after updating the android studie it works perfectly in order to use the remaining project without error message android N in relation to bundle.

Thank you for your time and patience for helping my case!

Answer (score 0):

you have to change 
in app/build.gradle before opening your project
    compileSdkVersion 'N'
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.0 rc1'
        targetSdkVersion 'N'

to 
    compileSdkVersion '24'
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.0'
        targetSdkVersion '24'